# what is a rank-n tensor

Tags: tensor-products

So I am taking this mechanics class over the summer the book introduces the concept of rank 2 tensors for moment of inertia as any physics book it didn't give the concept justice I understand how to play with it etc for solving problems, however I am still not satisfied with not understanding exactly what that is can someone maybe explain to me what is exactly a rank-n tensor.

Comment: Did you try wikipedia yet?

Comment: Are you looking for the precise mathematical definition or useful (intuitive) ways of thinking about them?

Comment: @John I have looked at the wikipedia definition which required understanding tensor product to begin with and that always leads me to open like million tabs and look through everything for hrs. I just want to understand them precisely and maybe some examples.

Comment: @Winther the precise mathematical definition.

Comment: The precise definition can be given by multilinear map. That can be found in the wikipedia page.

Comment: I see so I have to read all the literature I guess alright if someone could give me a useful intuitive ways about thinking them and when I read the literature I will make better connections that would be really nice.

Comment: You can find some answers about that [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/128026/how-to-understand-the-definition-of-vector-and-tensor/).